# Split a multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Because of the way it is being received (via ajax) it is being read as a string instead of an array
using `.split(',')` doesn't work here.

`console.log` shows it as `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` so I know the data is going through, however if I were to put the array directly in the page it shows properly as `array array`

This is the ajax with the recommendation given below. It still comes as plaintext.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php" + "?param=" + param,
    type: "POST",
    data: 'data',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        object = JSON.parse(data);
        filters();
    }
})
```

Comment: try alternative by (array)(your array)

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: first type cast your array which you are checking with console

Comment: I am still fairly new to JS. How would i do that?

Comment: object = (array)JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Doing that I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'

Comment: try giving it to data directly and then parse it

Comment: Do you mean without setting datatype to json?

Comment: JSON.parse((array)data);

Comment: Wouldnt that be an unterminated statement?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse()` to convert from string to array:

```js
var arr = JSON.parse('[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]')
console.log(arr[0])
```

Comment: It is still coming as plaintext

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a multidimensional array by parsing it as a JSON string:

```
 var parsedArray = JSON.parse(yourString);
```

Comment: I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2'

Comment: Should work on strings like the one you posted. Maybe the string has unwanted white space or unescaped control chars.

Comment: I figured out the error I had to encode it as json and specify datatype. But it is still coming as plaintext.